# Apigee send push notification to all devices fails on the server

Tags: push-notification, push, apigee

I am trying to use `apigee` sdk js example of sending push notification. As I need to send push messages to all devices I changed the devicePath:

```
var devicePath = "devices/"+client.getDeviceUUID()+"/notifications";
```

to

```
var devicePath = "devices/*/notifications";
```

Calling `client.sendPushToDevice` then succeeds and reaches the `apigee` server but it shows Failed status in the Message History and no messages are delivered. Can you please advise how to fix it?

Comment: What's the name of your notifier?

Comment: Did you register all of your devices before sending the message?

Comment: The name of the notifier is ApplicationProd, the devices were registered as push notifications work when I am using apigee web site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using matrixed parameters to query for all devices:

var devicePath = "devices;ql=*/notifications";